# How to use Plop Boot Manager to boot from USB in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I failed to upgrade from Ubuntu12.04 to 12.10, so I decide to make a fresh installation of 12.10. My old computer **doesn't support booting from usb**, and its **cd-rom is broken**.
I know ***Plop Boot Manager*** can make my computer boot from usb. I know how to use it in *Windows*, and I did use it when I tranfered from Win-XP to Ubuntu 12.04. But now, I don't know how to use it under *Linux*.

As far as I know, despite of the lengthy documentation, using Plop to boot from usb under Windows is as simple as double clicking a *bat* file. But doc for linux is not that straitfoward and contains daunting terminologies such as LILO for a Linux newbie. What makes it worse is that I'm not a native English speaker.

So could someone show me a brief and concise instruction how to boot from usb?

Answer (score 0):

rather late, but pls see if this can help you:
https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/445010:weekend-project-use-the-plop-boot-manager-to-boot-older-computers-from-usb